# encoding in vb.net and javascript

Tags: javascript, vb.net, encoding

I have a javascript function which  contain file name, folder id, etc and store the  values  in cookies, and try to access the value in page load of "FileUploader.aspx".  below is my javascript function

```
function cookieFileUploader(name, value) {
    debugger

    var date = new Date();

    date.setTime(date.getTime() + COOKIEXPIRINGTIME);
        var expires = "; expires=" + date.toGMTString();
         //var encodedDocumentName = encodeURI(value);
          //Encoder.EncodeType = "entity";

       //var Encodedoc = Encoder.htmlEncode(value);
        //document.cookie = name + "=" + Encodedoc + expires + "; path=/";
      document.cookie = name + "=" + value + expires + "; path=/";
    winstyle = "width=390, height=335,margin-top=0,scrollbars=no,toolbar=no, menubar=no,resizable=no,directories=no,location=no";
    progressIndicatorWindow = window.open("FileUploader.aspx", "mywindow", winstyle);

}
```

now I want to pass the filename with japanese and chinese characters.while i am doing so the file changed in pageload with some square values. i tried encoding the file name in javascript using encodeURI and try to decode in pageload using server.htmldecode(). Is it right way? if not so please provide me a right solution.I want the filename in pageload event of fileUploader,.aspx

Comment: I think the first thing what you have to do is to set the HTML encoding with the meta tag. (Note: You have to synchronized the browser encoding with server's encoding settings).

Answer (score 0):

Use `encodeURIComponent` in javascript and then `HttpUtility.UrlDecode` on the server - that should do it.